# Database Fundamental Questions

Tags: database, relational-database

Please help me answer these database fundamental questions?

1. If you create an index on a table (that has millions of rows of data in it), which one of the following will NOT be a result of that action?
   a.  Faster data access
   b.  Reduction of redundant data
   c.  Better performance in some cases
   d.  No performance improvement in some cases.
2. Which of the following best describes a clustered index?
   a.  An index where the data is clustered together.
   b.  An index where the index information is clustered together.
   c.  An index where the index information is clustered according to the data.
   d.  An index where the physical and logical order of the data are the same.
3. Table A has a column B, that is included in 5 different indexes.  This table is updated very frequently.  What will you encounter because of this scheme?
   a.  Faster access when issuing a command with column B in the join clause
   b.  Increased cost of maintaining the indexes when column B is updated
   c.  Increased performance of select/insert/delete/updates commands to the table
   d.  Slower access when using a select command involving column B
4. Which of the following best describes the role of the Optimizer?
   a.  Optimizing the database
   b.  Making optimum use of the storage space when storing the data
   c.  Constructing query plans based on index statistics
   d.  Making optimum use of all system resources.
5. Consider the following schema and query…
   QUERY :     select * 
   from 
   campus_config, 
   config_ref, 
   campus 
   where 
   campus_id=4 and 
   campus_id=cc_campus_id 
   a.  How many columns will this query return ? 
   b.  Is there anything wrong with this query? If so, what is it and how would you fix it?

Comment: I think : 1-->b , 2-->d , 3-->b , 4-->c (assuming we are speaking about query optimizer). , 5(a) --> number of columns in query = sum of number of columns in the all three tables , 5(b) --> yes ,it does not join (campus_config and config_ref) tables, we can fix it by: where campus_id=4 and campus_id=cc_campus_id and config_ref.id = campus_config.config_ref_id

Answer (score 0):

To give this question an answer:

1. b
2. d
3. b
4. c (assuming we are speaking about query optimizer)
5. (a): number of columns in query = sum of number of columns in the all three tables 
   (b): yes, it does not join (campus_config and config_ref) tables, we can fix it by:

   where campus_id=4 and campus_id=cc_campus_id and config_ref.id = campus_config.config_ref_id